# Quick way to search nested objectsY in objectsX in list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, search, optimization

I have optimization problem with list of objects. Those objects also contains list of other objects. I need to execute code below many times:

```
var result = objectsList.Where(d=>d.subObject.Where(w=>w.name == "WhatIamLookingFor").Count() > 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

This code is working fine, but it execute very slow. How can I improve performance?

Currently that search execute about 30 seconds.

Comment: Are you always filtering on subObject.name (i.e. a single property) or could you be filtering on an arbitrary property of subObnect?

Comment: @bytefire I am always using only subObject.name for filtering.

Comment: in that case check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `HashSet<string>` (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to every object of objectsList. This hash set will contain name property of subObject.

Then change the query to this

```
var result = objectsList.Where(d=>d.hashSetNames.Contains("WhatIamLookingFor")).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is a bit of replication but it should speed up your query. The reason is that [Contains][1] on HashSet is O(1) operation, i.e. it takes constant time irrespective of the number of elements in the hash set.

Trade off is that you will have to add name to the hash set every time you add a subObject and also remove that name when all subObjects with that name have been removed or their names have been changed. This is classic trade off whenever you create an index: faster query times come at cost of slower inserts and updates.

**Update**

If searching fast on subObject name is crucial then you can create a `Dictionary<string, List<objectsListObjects>>`. Let's call it `index`. `index` is a mapping from `subObject.name` that you search on to list of objects that contain at least one `subObject` with that name. When you add a `subObject` to an `objectsListObject`, then you can call the following:

```
index[subObject.name].Add(objectsListObject);
```

Then you can retrieve the list of objects with the name that you're looking for in O(1), i.e. by simply indexing into `index`. Obviously it comes with its own constraints, specially when updating names in subObjects.

Note that by creating a separate Dictionary in addition to objectsList, you're *not* doubling the memory consumption. Dictionary and the Lists in that dictionary only hold references to original objects and not full copies.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. objectsList is created only once and then is used only for that search queries. Is it possible to improve it even more with some kind 2 level "index"?

Answer (score 0):

At least you should replace this:

```
d=>d.subObject.Where(w=>w.name == "WhatIamLookingFor").Count() > 0
```

with this:

```
d=>d.subObject.Any(w=>w.name == "WhatIamLookingFor")
```

because your code searches **all** occurrences of subobjects, whose name is equals to "WhatIamLookingFor". `Any` returns when first match is found (that is, count is > 0).

P.S. I'm suggesting, that you're using `List<T>`/`Collection<T>` (or its descendants).

Comment: Thank you for tips, but unlucky it isn't enough. Maybe should i rewrite it to foreach(..) {foreach(){}} search on my own? I don't have experience if it would be faster